# PerformanceWarning - Pandas and Pytables, can I fix this?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, pytables

I am getting the following PerformanceWarning:

```
"PerformanceWarning: 
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->mixed-integer,key->block0_values] [items->   ['File1', 'File2', 'File3', 'File4', 'File5']]

warnings.warn(ws, PerformanceWarning)"
```

This is because of the "file_attributes" df (see code below), which contains a mix of several things:

Typical output for store.file_attributes (basically a bunch of dictionary key/value pairs with some nested dictionaries):

File1  \

duration                                                         0.2
linescan file            GluAlone-001_Cycle00001_LineProfileData.csv
primary                               {'unit': 'mV', 'divisor': 0.1}
sampling                                                       20000
secondary                          {'unit': 'pA', 'divisor': 0.0005}
voltage recording file  GluAlone-001_Cycle00001_VoltageRecording_001

File2  \

duration                                                         0.2
linescan file            GluAlone-001_Cycle00002_LineProfileData.csv
primary                               {'unit': 'mV', 'divisor': 0.1}
sampling                                                       20000
secondary                          {'unit': 'pA', 'divisor': 0.0005}
voltage recording file  GluAlone-001_Cycle00002_VoltageRecording_001

ETC.

The function I've written for this is pulling in data from another function that parses a folder of data files:

```
def convert_folder_hdf5(folder, save_loc = None):
    if save_loc==None:
        save_loc = folder

    filename = save_loc+ '\\' + (folder.split('\\')[-1])+'.h5'
    store = pd.HDFStore(filename, format = "table", complevel=9, complib='blosc')
    data = import_folder(folder)

    store['voltage_recording'] = data['voltage recording']
    store['linescan'] = data['linescan']
    store['file_attributes'] = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['file attributes'])


    #store.close()

    return store
```

I'm not sure how to deal with this warning, though. Searching around the two posts I found that might be appropriate contained solutions that did not get me anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: well you have mixed dtypes in a column. never a good idea. show ``df.info()`` for these frames. you want a single dtype on each column, and not ``object``, unless its all strings.

Comment: Right. Each File label (File 1, 2, 3, etc.) is a column, and there are going to be some mixed values in there. It's just a container for the different pieces of information that I have to pull out of .xml files about the actual data (file name, some conversion factors, etc.). I'm mainly using it for reference / to keep track of things. 

If I'm not concerned about any actual performance issues (since I don't think there are going to be any significant ones), can it just be ignored in some way?

Comment: You *could* simply set these as attributes: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#hdfstore, or filter the warning, or just make the entire column a string (``astype(str)``). not sure what you are really doing. FYI, this is not typical data to store in an HDF5 file (are you really wanting a ACID type database?)

Comment: That had been my original intention, but I didn't realize that the attributes had to be tied to one (or more) of the storer values. For my purpose it doesn't make sense to put the file attributes with "voltage_recording" or "linescan", as there is information with regards to both in the "file_attributes" dictionary. I could split it up, but it's honestly not worth it as again, it's simply there as a reference should I need it at some point. 
Is there a way to set attributes for the .h5 file overall instead of for specific keys?

Comment: you can set them almost direct, you just need the correct node (which can be root), e.g. ``store.root.attributes = dict(foo = 1)`` (and retrieve simliary). This is just a pickle and has a 64KB limit IIRC.

Comment: Oh perfect. That's exactly what I was trying to do from the get go. If you put that in an answer I'll mark this as answered. Thanks!