# store.root.attributes not saving - Pandas and Pytables

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

So I'm parsing data files into pandas dataframes and then saving the files to hdf5 using HDFStore. Code:

```
def convert_folder_hdf5(folder, save_loc=None):
    if save_loc is None:
        save_loc = folder

    filename = save_loc+'\\' + (folder.split('\\')[-1])+'.h5'
    store = pd.HDFStore(filename, format="table", complevel=9, complib='blosc')
    data = import_folder(folder)

    if data['voltage recording'] is not None:
        store['voltage_recording'] = data['voltage recording']
    if data['linescan'] is not None:
       store['linescan'] = data['linescan']

    store.root.attributes = data['file attributes']

    store.close()
```

However, I go to access store.root.attributes I'm given:

```
tables.exceptions.NoSuchNodeError: group ``/`` does not have a child named  ``attributes``
```

store.root returns (this particular folder has no linescan files):

```
/ (RootGroup) ''
  children := ['voltage_recording' (Group)]
```

Just working in the console I can manually do:

```
store.root.attributes = data['file attributes']
```

And then when I call store.root.attributes I get what I'm expecting to get.

However, if I then re-save the file, and re-open it what was set in store.root.attributes is gone (I get the same error as above).

Answer (score 1):

You can't store directly in a node, but rather in the attributes section of the node. From [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#hdfstore), you have to actually create a node and use the `.attrs` attribute to grab where you can actually store things.

Here's a way to do it directly:

```
In [16]: store.root._v_attrs.attributes = 'bar'

In [17]: store.root._v_attrs
Out[17]: 
/._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 5 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    PYTABLES_FORMAT_VERSION := '2.1',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0',
    attributes := 'bar']
```

Pandas is still developing a more generic API to get/set attributes, feel free to comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7334

Further, specifying `format='table'` when opening the `HDFStore` is ignored. This ONLY is applicable on a `to_hdf`. You can't have a format for an entire store, just object-by-object.http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#table-format

Comment: I'm a bit confused - did something change about how this works recently? 

I actually had a previous question about doing this, and your response then was similar to what I have in my code sample above. 

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232707/performancewarning-pandas-and-pytables-can-i-fix-this

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking their. On a non-root node you *can* store (using ``.attrs``). But this ONLY works with ``store.get_storer('df').attrs``. Otherwise use the method above.